# javascript popup data getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am using javascript to display pop up whenver user will hover a link, i Have a list of links ..pop up will contain some data related to link.
whenever i hover on a link pop up comes with the data but that is of last record of the list.
how to get data related to link??

can anyone please help me?

thank you.

please find the code below

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
      var moveLeft = 20;
      var moveDown = 10;

      $('#web'+'<%= website.id%>').hover(function(e) {
        $('div.pop-up').show();
      }, function() {
        $('div.pop-up').hide();
      });

      $('#web'+'<%=website.id%>').mousemove(function(e) {
        $("div.pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
      });

    });
    </script>
```

HTML :

```
<% for website in @websites %>
<tr>
    <td class="website" id="web_<%= website.id%>"><%= link_to h(truncate(website.name, :length => 30)), website_path(website) %></td>
    <td><%= website_status_image(website) %></td>
</tr>
  <div class="pop-up">
    <h3>Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</h3>
    <p><%= website.name%></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many popups on your page and jQuery doesn't know which one you want to show and shows the last one (from collection). Also you shouldn't place any html tags outside `<td>` tag.

There are many ways to implement this feature. You should find your popup using jQuery (`.closest()`, `.parent()` methods). 
Here is the modified code:

**html**

```
    <tr>
     <td class="website"><%= link_to h(truncate(website.name, :length => 30)), website_path(website) %>
       <div class="pop-up" style='display: none;'>
        <h3>Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</h3>
        <p><%= website.name%></p>
       </div>
     </td>
    <td><%= website_status_image(website) %></td>
</tr>
```

**js**

```
$('.website').hover(function(e) {
    $('div.pop-up', this).show();
  }, function() {
    $('div.pop-up', this).hide();
  });
```

It would be better if you place your website name into html data-attribute in `<tr>` tag, create one popup div next to your table and then place this data in your popup every time when user hovers a link.

**html**

```
<table>
    <% for website in @websites %>
    <tr>
    <td class="website" data-name='<%= website.name%>'><%= link_to h(truncate(website.name, :length => 30)), website_path(website) %></td>
    <td><%= website_status_image(website) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table> 

...

<div class="pop-up" style='display: none;'>
    <h3>Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</h3>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.website').hover(function(e) {
        var popup = $('div.pop-up').show();
        $('p', popup).html($(this).data('name'));
      }, function() {
        $('div.pop-up').hide();
      });
```

**But I recomend you to use jQuery plugins or [bootsrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)**

Comment: thank you for your reply..i dont want only website name but other details also which i need to show in pop-up box..your suggestion  is nice..i have achieve the solution through different path as i have provided uniq id to the pop-up list as well now its working fine.

Comment: it's not recomended to use lots of popups - it litters your page and takes more time to load. you should provide other details in data attributes and use one popup template instead of many

Comment: I do understand your suggestion..but i have more than hundred links on a page..and the requirement is to show some details of every link on hover of a link so i dont have anyother option to show them.

Comment: You generate popup for every record. It means that you have a lot of unnecessary html markup. Instead of this you could create only one popup next to your table and insert details  depending on hovered row as I've showed